# How to Implement an optimal Stochastic Control Optimization?

Tags: stochastic-processes, optimization, stochastic-control

I'm currently working on an stochastic optimal control problem applied to a portfolio asset allocation. In principle, the problem is to maximize the return of a fixed income portfolio under certain VaR constraint.

My question is:

1- How would one go about solving these problems numerically (Monte-Carlo method, etc.)

2- Can some one direct me to a source for an exposition of the material (seeing some code would be awesome!)

Comment: This is too broad, a good answer could easily be made in a book.

Comment: Very challenging problem, the answer(s) will depend on the specific model formulation. (Care will have to be taken that the model is solvable in the first place, which is not an easy task in stochastic optimal control).